# How to apply smooth scroll on click to div on the same page?

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll, css-transitions

I want to apply smooth scroll to a div on the same page.
Eg. when I click on link with href="#that-div" I want it to smoothly scroll to that div and not jump right at it.
Sorry for my English and thank you in advance for answers.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I had no idea what should I do, but I tried palaѕн's method and it works like a charm :P
ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('button').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#what').offset().top
        }, 'slow');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nMqJ9/)

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#yourId").offset().top }, 'slow');
```

for downside scroll: [How to Scroll Down - JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650170/how-to-scroll-down-jquery)