# How to trigger keypress with click?

Tags: jquery, dom, event-handling

I know that there are a lot of other threads with this question, but I think I'm doing something gravely wrong because nothing seems to work.

I'm new at jQuery, so I'm still learning. Basically, my question is:

I want to make it so that when I click on an element on my website, it is essentially pressing the down arrow on the keyboard for the entire page.

So let's say I have a DOM object, a div with id "downarrow".

This is the jQuery code I have to make it happen, but it just doesn't work.

```
$("#downarrow").click(function(){
    var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
    e.which = 40;
    e.keyCode = 40;
    $(document).trigger(e);
});
```

Any thoughts or suggestions why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you expect triggering a keypress on the document to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Definitive way to trigger keypress events with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery)

Comment: Just to scroll the page down.

Comment: You probably don't want to trigger this even on the document which is presumably the whole DOM, you need the piece that needs scrolling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Scroll Down - JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650170/how-to-scroll-down-jquery)