# Scroll down function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

how to write a function to scroll down in typescript !

I have search a lot for this solution, but seems like there is not answer for this sort of question !

So what I want to that to have a Scroll down option for the body part which have to write on typescript !

I hope my question makes sense and someone knows how to solve this problem !

Comment: Same as you would in JS. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650170/how-to-scroll-down-jquery

Comment: @JohnnyHK Thanks a lot :) You are my hero :)