# How can I load a container initially scrolled down?

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-4, web-applications, chat

I am trying to create a web application (in php) and in that I am creating a chat box for the two type of user to communicate with each other. The chat box is shown just like WhatsApp Web and everything is working fine and the data is coming via ajax. It is made using bootstrap 4.

The problem is that when the page loads it shows older messages. It starts fetching all the messages using ajax and the content is shown but I want it to be scrolled down just like WhatsApp or any other chat box you see. I just want it to show latest message and then a person can scroll up to see older messages but it should initially load at the bottom. And if a new message arrives from ajax it should scroll down automatically to the latest message.

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650170/how-to-scroll-down-jquery you may find useful answers.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca Thanks for sharing the link I have already gone through that. Well those are the solution for whole page I am using a part of my page for chat-box and those solutions don't work on that properly.